# Override the let value in schematron

Tags: xml, schema, schematron

I want to override a defined let variable in schematron files from the root schematron. Is that possible? I must pass a value from the root schematron file to the child one but the child one has the one that is defined. I have to control its value from the root_schematron.xml. The other schema files are published ones and I must not change its content. Any help will be appreciated.

root_schematron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" >

    <sch:extends href="UBL-TR_Main_Schematron.xml"/>
    <let name="type" value="'earchive'"/>
</sch:schema>
```

UBL-TR_Main_Schematron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" 
            xmlns:ef="http://www.efatura.gov.tr/envelope-namespace">
    
    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Codelist.xml#codes"/>
    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Common_Schematron.xml#abstracts"/>    
    
    <let name="type" value="'efatura'"/>
    
</sch:schema>
```

Comment: So what happens if you try that? The Schematron spec says "It is an error for a variable to be multiply defined in the current schema, phase, pattern and rule". As I understand the `sch:include` to perform a simple textual inclusion I would see that as having multiple definitions for the same variable.

Comment: It gives the error "Duplicate variable" . include not working in this scenario and gives the error that says include must be used for patterns not the whole schema. So, ı am using the extends tag for include the child schemas.